# Temporal js yearMonth.subtract return the same month

Tags: javascript, date, ecmascript-temporal

I am trying to use Temporal [yearMonth.subtract](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/plainyearmonth.html#subtract) but is not working. `add` is working as expected.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-knuth-20ov2?file=/src/index.js

```js
import { Temporal } from "@js-temporal/polyfill";

const currentMonth = Temporal.Now.plainDate("gregory").toPlainYearMonth();

console.log("currentMonth", currentMonth.toString());
console.log("after", currentMonth.add({ months: 1 }).toString());
console.log("before", currentMonth.subtract({ months: 1 }).toString());
```

```js
currentMonth 2021-12-01[u-ca=gregory] 
after 2022-01-01[u-ca=gregory] 
before 2021-12-01[u-ca=gregory]
```

Comment: It feels like the implementation there is wrong. I'm debugging it and at some point it converts the months to subtract to how many days are there in a month (30) and it attempts to subtract that `month` number of times. However, when the actual subtraction happens it calculates `day - days` - the latter is the `30` I mentioned and `day` is, for some reason, `31`. And it does this every time in the loop, so it ends up dropping `2021-12-31` to `2021-12-01` four times. I'm not quite sure *why* yet.

Comment: @VLAZ sorry I edited the question in the meantime ^^ Even outside a loop it has the same issue.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear - I didn't mean *your* loop. The implementation that the library uses has a loop that is effectively `for (let i = 0; i < Math.abs(monthsToSubtract); i++)`. So, because you want to subtract four months, it loops four times. However, during the loop, it subtracts 30 days from the current date. Yet the current date is set to be `31` - that's because earlier the library checks whether you're doing addition or subtraction and then *setting* the day to be `1` (if adding) or the last day of the current month (if subtracting). Seems wrong.

Comment: OK, so using `.plainDateISO()` instead of `.plainDate("gregory")` works - it's the calendar messing up the calculations. It seems to make a PlainYearMonth date into one with a day always. Still not sure why, though and how to get it to work with a calendar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the OP ought to work as you expected, this is a bug in v0.2.0 of that polyfill. It seems like it will be fixed in the shortly upcoming v0.3.0.

Comment: I confirm ```v0.3.0``` fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Applying the [Temporal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/index.html) [`toPlainYearMonth`](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/plaindate.html#toPlainYearMonth) method to `currentMonth` before the addition/subtraction operation is causing the problem.

This works as expected:

```
const currentMonth = Temporal.Now.plainDate("gregory");

console.log("currentMonth", currentMonth.toPlainYearMonth().toString());
console.log("after", currentMonth.add({ months: 1 }).toPlainYearMonth().toString());
console.log("before", currentMonth.subtract({ months: 1 }).toPlainYearMonth().toString());
```

Console output:

```
currentMonth 2021-12-01[u-ca=gregory] 
after 2022-01-01[u-ca=gregory] 
before 2021-11-01[u-ca=gregory]
```